# How to replace Mandrill's *| |* symbols?

Tags: mandrill

Is there any chance to replace the mandrill's *| |* symbols?

The CMS i'm using (MODX) has its own symbols to enclose the tags, eg: [[+   ]]

The case is that I also have "read on web" link, where the page on the web needs to generate dynamic content as well.

I have googled and searched on http://help.mandrill.com but still no luck.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use different symbols in your emails - those are how Mandrill's system recognizes merge tags and to replace them in the HTML and/or text of your email.  You'd need to convert any placeholders you have or want for the email to that format, so you can pass the data to Mandrill as expected. If it's going to mirror what you're putting on the web, then you probably just want to have something that transforms strings, for example, to convert your CMS tags to Mandrill tags specifically for the emails.

Answer (score 0):

@kaitlin-mandrill,

Exactly,
I just figured it out.

I need to replace it **right before** it is sent.

More or less, [this is the code](https://github.com/virtudraft/virtuNewsletter/commit/85e25077d38bbf47a277b639a0af262c9e986242#diff-0e9fc9e49eb85ed247aa86a5d0b2783cR60).

Hopefully it's useful for anyone else.